# Does Spark supports melt and dcast

Tags: r, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, melt

We use melt and dcast to convert data from wide->long and long->wide format. 
Refer http://seananderson.ca/2013/10/19/reshape.html for more details.

Either scala or SparkR is fine.

I've gone through this [blog](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/09/16/spark-1-5-dataframe-api-highlights-datetimestring-handling-time-intervals-and-udafs.html) and [scala functions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$) and [R API](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/R/index.html).
I don't see functions which does similar job.

Is there any equivalent function in Spark? If not, is there any other way to do it in Spark?

Comment: Doesn't seem like it. If you can fit your data into memory, use `as.data.frame()` to convert the Spark DataFrame to a native data.frame, reshape that, and write it back to Spark.

Comment: Because there is none. You'll need to write it yourself.

Answer (score 10):

[Reshaping Data with Pivot in Spark](https://databricks.com/blog/2016/02/09/reshaping-data-with-pivot-in-spark.html) gives support for reshaping with `pivot`. I understood `melt` is roughly the reverse of pivot also called `unpivot`. I'm relatively new to `Spark`. With my knowledge i tried to implement melt operation.

```
    def melt(df: DataFrame, columns: List[String]): DataFrame ={

    val restOfTheColumns =  df.columns.filterNot(columns.contains(_))
    val baseDF = df.select(columns.head, columns.tail: _*)
    val newStructure =StructType(baseDF.schema.fields ++ List(StructField("variable", StringType, true), StructField("value", StringType, true)))
    var newdf  = sqlContext.createDataFrame(sqlContext.sparkContext.emptyRDD[Row], newStructure)

    for(variableCol <- restOfTheColumns){
      val colValues = df.select(variableCol).map(r=> r(0).toString)
      val colRdd=baseDF.rdd.zip(colValues).map(tuple => Row.fromSeq(tuple._1.toSeq.:+(variableCol).:+(tuple._2.toString)))
      var colDF =sqlContext.createDataFrame(colRdd, newStructure)
      newdf =newdf.unionAll(colDF)
    }
    newdf
  }
```

It does the work. But i am not very sure about the efficiency.

```
+-----+---+---+----------+------+
| name|sex|age|    street|weight|
+-----+---+---+----------+------+
|Alice|  f| 34| somewhere|    70|
|  Bob|  m| 63|   nowhere|   -70|
|Alice|  f|612|nextstreet|    23|
|  Bob|  m|612|      moon|     8|
+-----+---+---+----------+------+
```

Can be used as

```
melt(df, List("name", "sex"))
```

The result is as below:

```
+-----+---+--------+----------+
| name|sex|variable|     value|
+-----+---+--------+----------+
|Alice|  f|     age|        34|
|  Bob|  m|     age|        63|
|Alice|  f|     age|       612|
|  Bob|  m|     age|       612|
|Alice|  f|  street| somewhere|
|  Bob|  m|  street|   nowhere|
|Alice|  f|  street|nextstreet|
|  Bob|  m|  street|      moon|
|Alice|  f|  weight|        70|
|  Bob|  m|  weight|       -70|
|Alice|  f|  weight|        23|
|  Bob|  m|  weight|         8|
+-----+---+--------+----------+
```

I hope it is useful and appreciate your comments if there is room for improvements.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a `spark.ml.Transformer` that just uses dataset manipulations (no RDD stuff)

```
case class Melt(meltColumns: String*) extends Transformer{

  override def transform(in: Dataset[_]): DataFrame = {
    val nonMeltColumns =  in.columns.filterNot{ meltColumns.contains }
    val newDS = in
      .select(nonMeltColumns.head,meltColumns:_*)
      .withColumn("variable", functions.lit(nonMeltColumns.head))
      .withColumnRenamed(nonMeltColumns.head,"value")

    nonMeltColumns.tail
      .foldLeft(newDS){ case (acc,col) =>
        in
          .select(col,meltColumns:_*)
          .withColumn("variable", functions.lit(col))
          .withColumnRenamed(col,"value")
          .union(acc)
      }
      .select(meltColumns.head,meltColumns.tail ++ List("variable","value") : _*)
  }

  override def copy(extra: ParamMap): Transformer = defaultCopy(extra)

  @DeveloperApi
  override def transformSchema(schema: StructType): StructType = ???

  override val uid: String = Identifiable.randomUID("Melt")
}
```

Here's a test that uses it

```
"spark" should "melt a dataset" in {
    import spark.implicits._
    val schema = StructType(
      List(StructField("Melt1",StringType),StructField("Melt2",StringType)) ++
      Range(3,10).map{ i => StructField("name_"+i,DoubleType)}.toList)

    val ds = Range(1,11)
      .map{ i => Row("a" :: "b" :: Range(3,10).map{ j => Math.random() }.toList :_ *)}
      .|>{ rows => spark.sparkContext.parallelize(rows) }
      .|>{ rdd => spark.createDataFrame(rdd,schema) }

    val newDF = ds.transform{ df =>
      Melt("Melt1","Melt2").transform(df) }

    assert(newDF.count() === 70)
  }
```

.|> is the scalaZ pipe operator

Answer (score 0):

Spark DataFrame has `explode` method which provides R `melt` functionality.
Example which works in Spark 1.6.1:

```
// input df has columns (anyDim, n1, n2)
case class MNV(measureName: String, measureValue: Integer);
val dfExploded = df.explode(col("n1"), col("n2")) {
  case Row(n1: Int, n2: Int) =>
  Array(MNV("n1", n1), MNV("n2", n2))
}
// dfExploded has columns (anyDim, n1, n2, measureName, measureValue)
```